# Add distinct statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008

```
 Protected Sub ImageButton2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles ImageButton2.Click
        Dim pa As String
        pa = Server.MapPath("~\\Morfk\\")
        TextBox4.Text = pa
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(TextBox4.Text + FileUpload1.FileName)
        sqlcon.Open()
        Dim sqlcmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [aldia db].[dbo].[morfak] ([stnamei] ,[kiedi],[addressi],[morfk] ,[emaili],[nuphone])VALUES('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "' ,'" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + FileUpload1.FileName + "' ,'" + TextBox5.Text + "'," + TextBox6.Text + ")", sqlcon)
        sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("the process of sending Facility has done ")
        sqlcon.Close()
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox3.Text = ""
        TextBox4.Text = ""
        TextBox5.Text = ""
        TextBox6.Text = ""
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you actually have a question?

Comment: where to add code to prevent repeat any name in TextBox3.Text ?

Comment: What do you mean "prevent repeat any name"? Perhaps an example can help

Comment: sorry
for example if i enter a project title  , after that someone enter the same name of project title , i need code to show a message e.g: "the project title exist"

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your SQLQuery as below. Then based on the return value you can display appropriate comment.

```
"IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [aldia db].[dbo].[morfak] WHERE [stnamei]='" +TextBox1.Text+"')
BEGIN
RETURN -1
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO [aldia db].[dbo].[morfak] ([stnamei] ,[kiedi],[addressi],[morfk] ,[emaili],[nuphone])VALUES('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "' ,'" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + FileUpload1.FileName + "' ,'" + TextBox5.Text + "'," + TextBox6.Text + ")
RETURN 0
END"
```